# How do I determine if I'm going to get an inline or redirecting java install?

Tags: java, applet, sun

I'm using the following Java Deployment Toolkit:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit

Now, I've searched the docs, and I cannot find when the inline java installer is possible. If the user has absolutely no java installed, they will be redirected to the get java page. If java has been installed on a machine at one point, the inline installer seems to trigger, even after I've supposedly uninstalled the JRE and java plugins for both FF and IE.

What gives? Is there an easy way to check whether or not a redirect is coming? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user has Java 1.4.2+, the install will be an upgrade install.